# Multiplying a Matrix (obtain value)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matrix multiplications (obtaining values)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36310/matrix-multiplications-obtaining-values)

Hi,

I have a final tomorrow and it includes multiplying matrices (getting a table of values) but i do not understand how he is getting some of the numbers

something like this

suppose the matrices are

```
 A3X4  B4X5    C5x7    D7X2
```

in the results table he has

```
          A    B     C       D
    A     0    60    165     134
    B           0    140     110
    C                0       70
    D                        0

     A     B      C      D
A    A     A*B    A*B*C  A*B*C*D
B          B      B*C    B*C*D
C                 C      C*D
D                        D
```

How is he getting 164 unders C for example? I know how he is getting the twi dimentional ones like for instance  the 140 under C would be B*C which is 4X5X7  = 140 but I have no idea how he is getting for the A*B*C = 165

Thank you

Comment: It looks to me as if the table contains operation counts. For example A*B requires 3*5 dot products, each requiring 4 ops and so A*B requires 60 ops in total. I reckon the table is showing the least op count way to compute A*B*C*D, ie A*(B*(C*D); 70 ops for C*D (5x7 * 7x2) an additional 40 to compute B*(C*D) (4x5 * 5x2) and finally an additional 24 to compute A*(B*(C*D)) (3x4 * 4x2).

Answer (score 0):

If you're multiplying `E = A*B*C*D`, then `E` ought to be a 3x2 matrix, right?

And the rule for matrix multiplication is simple:

Given `W(m,n), U(m, p), and V(p, n)` then `W = U*V`

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int k = 0; k < p; k++)
        {
            sum += u[i, k]*v{k, j];   
        }
        w[i, j] = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know what you say, I know that 3 matrices that are for example
A3X4, B4X5, C5X7, would give me a 3X7, but thats not what i need... what i need to know is the number of multiplications..i think thats what that value means,,,

in example above i need to  figure out how to get A*B*C = 165 considering A = 3X4, B=4x5, C=5X7

Comment: Yes, you have to calculate A*B, then multiply that by C, then multiply that by D.

Comment: Ok so, i did A*B = 3X5 = 15 A*B*C = 3X7 = 21 A*B*C*D = 3X2 if i add them up i get 42, so not good, then i tried
A*B =  3X4X5 = 60 and A*B*C = 3X5X7 = 105 when i add them i get 165 but now i cant get 110 :(